# If $R,S$ are reflexive relations, so are $R \oplus S$ and $R \setminus S$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

> Suppose $R$ and $S$ are reflexive relations on a set $A$. Prove or disprove each of these statements.
>
> a) $R\oplus S$ is reflexive.
>
> b) $R\setminus S$ is reflexive.

I think both of a) and b) are false, but I'm having trouble with coming up with counterexamples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What does it mean to say $(x,x) \in R \oplus S$, respectively $(x,x) \in R \setminus S$? Can both $R$ and $S$ be reflexive if this is the case?

---

The above amounts to a proof by contradiction. But we can avoid this; for example, by the following argument:

> Let $x \in A$. We know that $(x,x)\in R$ and $(x,x) \in S$. Therefore, by definition of $R \oplus S$ (resp. $R \setminus S$), $(x,x)\notin R \oplus S$. Hence $R \oplus S$ is not reflexive.

Comment: $(x,x)\in R\oplus S$ means that $x,x$ is only in $R$ and only in $S$ but not both?

Comment: Yes, indeed. So...?

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: So $(x,x)\in R$ and $(x,x)\in S$ cannot both be true. But $R$ and $S$ are reflexive. Hence...

Comment: Oh I see, so R and S cannot be both reflexive so the assumption doesn't hold. So it is essentially a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Indeed; I've also added an argument that avoids PbC.

Comment: But in order to disprove a) and b) I want to find counter-examples.

Comment: The argument shows that any reflexive $R$ and $S$ will work. Take e.g. $R = S = \Delta_A$, the diagonal relation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A \neq \emptyset$ consider $R=S= \{ (a,a) : a \in A \}$.